# How to print colours based on a text result, using two enums and a const char*?

Tags: c, enums, colors, printf

I am looking to print color of a result based on what that result is.
How can this be implemented with the following enums and char*?

0 Needs to be red, X needs to be white and Empty needs to be reset.

Being able to embed it into the below switch statement is the end result.

TIA.

````
enum color
{
        COLOR_RED,
        COLOR_WHITE,
        COLOR_RESET
};
enum token
{
        RED_TOKEN = 'O',
        WHITE_TOKEN = 'X',
        EMPTY_TOKEN = ' ',
        INVALID_TOKEN = EOF
};
const char* color_strings[NUM_COLORS] = { "\x1b[31m", "\x1b[37m", "\x1b[0m" };

       for (x = 0; x < BOARD_WIDTH; x++){ 
            printf("  ");
            switch (theboard[x][y])
            {
                case P_EMPTY:
                    printf(" ");
                    break;
                case P_RED:
                    printf("X");
                    break;
                case P_WHITE:
                    printf("O");
                    break;
                case P_INVALID:
                    printf("return !quit");
                    break;
            }```
````

Comment: What does `theboard[x][y]` contain? A character? or a int?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying to do. You write "0 Needs to be red, X needs to be white" and in the code you do `case P_RED: printf("X");` That seems to be a cntradiction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just print the color string before the text you want to give a specific color.

This code

```
enum color
{
        COLOR_RED,
        COLOR_WHITE,
        COLOR_RESET
};

int main(void)
{

  const char* color_strings[3] = { "\x1b[31m", "\x1b[37m", "\x1b[0m" };
  for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
  {
    printf("%sO", color_strings[COLOR_RED]);
    printf("%sX", color_strings[COLOR_WHITE]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

will give you alternating red O and white X.

[image]

If you want to use the `enum token` you can also do:

```
enum color
{
        COLOR_RED,
        COLOR_WHITE,
        COLOR_RESET
};

enum token
{
        RED_TOKEN = 'O',
        WHITE_TOKEN = 'X',
        EMPTY_TOKEN = ' ',
        INVALID_TOKEN = EOF
};

int main(void)
{

  const char* color_strings[3] = { "\x1b[31m", "\x1b[37m", "\x1b[0m" };
  for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
  {
    printf("%s%c", color_strings[COLOR_RED], RED_TOKEN);
    printf("%s%c", color_strings[COLOR_WHITE], WHITE_TOKEN);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't mention this explicitly but it makes the `switch()` in OPs code obsolete, using the `color_strings` array as lookup table with color enums as indices (which I would consider as improvement). ;-) If symbols have fix assigned colors, the `color_strings` entries could be simply extended to provide the `O`, `X` etc. as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I asked because I'm trying to find a way to do this, this specific way.  Otherwise next time I come across this issue there may be no workaround.

Comment: @jams I'm not sure what you mean by ".. this specific way" Can you explain a bit more

Comment: The answer can perfectly be applied to your _specific way_. What's wrong with it? It's the exact answer to _I am looking to print color of a result based on what that result is. How can this be implemented with the following enums and char*?_

Comment: @Scheff I agree that most likely the `switch` can be avoided. However, currently we can't say because OP never told us what `P_EMPTY`, `P_RED` ... are

Comment: My apologies, this solution was very acceptable. thankyou!

Comment: @jams I added a little more to the example. Maybe that's more in the way you are looking for

Comment: Amazing! @4386427 Thankyou